# HTML page cropped when printed

Tags: html, printing, crop

I have website that i trying to print and it comes out cropped. only 70% width showing on paper.

If i do print preview it and change scape to 70% then it prints entire page without cropping.

However how do i make it auto scale it by default because i dont want visitors who print without preview to get cropped page.

I tried with blank page and only one `<img />` tag (image width 1400px) and it still cropped. What's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can think of: Your printer has to convert the website to cm/inches. If we say you want to print an A4 sized paper with a common printer (which prints a resolution of 72dpi), then you can print a total width of 595px and a height of 794px. If you expect your website to get printed regularly, I recommend to provide a special "print version" of your website which meets that requirements - use e.g. the CSS3 media types: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp